# iOS device hangs when simple queries fired from Cordova SQLite plugin

Tags: javascript, ios, sqlite, cordova

I have used the SQLite plugin with Cordova to perform database operations on SQLite database. I am using [Cordova SQLite storage](http://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)  plugin with Cordova version 6.0 and X-Code 7.2. The iOS device hangs when and consumes more memory when executing below code.

The below code snippet opens a database connection:

```
 db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'sample.db', location: 2}, function(database){
    console.log('DB opened successfully in database.js');
    db = database;
    if(dbSuccessCallback != null){
        dbSuccessCallback(db);
    }
}, function(error){
    console.log('DB opening error in database.js');
    if(dbErrorCallback != null){
        dbErrorCallback(error);
    }
});
return db;
```

The below code snippet is used to insert the data in database

```
   db.sqlBatch(['create table if not exists app_settings(id integer primary key autoincrement,key_name text,value text)', 'create table if not exists department(id integer primary key autoincrement,department_name text,department_head text,no_of_employees integer)'],function(tx, result){
    console.log('Tables Created successfully');
}
```

Can someone tell me what mistake I am doing in above code or is their any other SQLite plugin or any other way of inserting records in sqlite database in iOS with Cordova?

Comment: Your link to Cordova SQLlite storage is dead. I've been struggling with SQLite plugins too. Finally using the cordova-sqlite-ext: https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext, which works awesome on iOS.

Comment: Please be aware of SQLite instead of SQLlite :).